# Update SmartEyeglass display every 40ms

Tags: android, user-interface, sony-smarteyeglass

I created a bitmap on the screen of my Sony SmartEyeglass like this:

```
private void updateLayout(){
    this.showBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

Now I want to update it every 40 milliseconds or so.

I tried calling it again and again from another thread and added `this.clearDisplay()` but it doesn't work.

How can I achieve regular update of the display?

**Update:**

I used the suggested code below.
Result: Stuttering image that overlaps the previous which doesn't get cleared from the screen.

Tried adding `canvas.drawRect(new Rect(0, 0, 500, 500), paint);` before redrawing.
Result: It still flickers, but now also won't show the new images.

Does anybody have any experience with real time graphics on SmartEyeglass.
Reloading the Extension with different message to draw from is not an option!

Comment: you can use postdelayed function of handler

Comment: can you give me some code? I have no idea how I would do that. :/

Comment: check my answer @RUB3N

Comment: @RUB3N  can you try this  canvas.drawColor(0, Mode.CLEAR); before calling the updateLayout() method.

Comment: Nope..still flickery. I don't know, but it seems to be the case that it only draws new graphics when a sensor event happens, but clears the screen more often and in between redraws. Weird.

Answer (score 1):

By creating a postDelayed() handler you can run a method periodically.

your code should be like this.

```
Handler handler = new Handler();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      handler.post(sendData);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
      super.onDestroy();
      handler.removeCallbacks(sendData);
}

private void updateLayout(){
    this.showBitmap(bitmap);
}


private final Runnable sendData = new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        try {
            //your method need to call here

                    updateLayout();

            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);  // 1000 milliseconds means 1 sec.. here you can change your time limit     
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks! Works, but when I add clearDisplay() I don't see anything any more. Does clear display also remove the Layout?

Comment: @RUB3N i will look into your updated question and try to resolve ASAP :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `showBitmap` use [`SmartEyeglassControlUtils.showBitmapWithCallback`](https://developer.sony.com/reference/seg-sdk/com/sony/smarteyeglass/extension/util/SmartEyeglassControlUtils#showBitmapWithCallback%28Bitmap,%20int%29). This way, after the rendering process on SmartEyeglass is done, you will receive a callback in `onResultShowBitmap`.

Inside of that callback, you can call `showBitmapWithCallback` again, to update the display as fast as possible.

The speed is limited to the speed of connection so:

1. Consider using `POWER_MODE_HIGH` to get wifi connection betweeen SmartEyeglass and phone
2. Consider using `showBitmapWithCallback(Bitmap bitmap, int x, int y, int transactionNumber)` with defining the x,y position and sending only that part of the `Bitmap`, which needs to be updated.

Comment: Is onResultShowBitmap a method I must override from ControllExtension? What are the parameters?

Comment: You need to update to the latest SDK, this update was added later. See the link to API reference I provided in the answer for: showBitmapWithCallback

Comment: I probably have the newest version - I got the sdk this monday

Comment: Probably not, as the showBitmapWithCallback is an existing method, also according to docs.

Comment: I double checked. It's up to date but the method is still undefined.

Comment: You are not calling it from the right place then: SmartEyeglassControlUtils.showBitmapWithCallback

Comment: Aha...thank you! :D - what is the parameter type int for?